# Drupal: "Unable to create CTools CSS cache directory. Check the permissions on your files directory."?

Tags: css, file, drupal, permissions, drupal-ctools

I am new to drupal, and am trying to help a friend with their drupal site, even though I specialize in Wordpress. i did some research on this and found results saying that by changing the permisions to 777 it would fix the issue.  I did that, and it still hasn't fixed it... I'm at a total loss as I havn't changed anything yet and it was working a few weeks ago

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may need to recursively set the permissions on the files directory to 777, since the ctools cache directory is deeper inside there.

`chmod -R 777 {files}`, where `{files}` is the path to your files directory. Also, you may need to use `sudo` before that if your server allows it.